# Silverlight doesn't have a Uri.IsLoopback property

Tags: c#, silverlight

In the absence of the `IsLoopback` property of the `System.Uri` class, what is the best available alternative?

And I know that Silverlight is no longer updated, but `IsLookback` has been around since Version 1 of .NET.  Is there any good reason why a useful property like this would be omitted from Silverlight?

Comment: You can be inspired by the reference source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=isloopback

Comment: Microsoft never talked much about why a specific API is not available.

Comment: It's possible there were technical difficulties that made it not worth their while.  Looking at Morten's link, the IsLoopback property is contained in a `!Silverlight` region.

Comment: There is a close vote against this question.  Since I am asking for an alternative, it's not just an anti-Microsoft rant.

Comment: Silverlight is supported to 2021: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?C2=12905&wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Edited accordingly.  Thanks.